# Pulling multiple files in simultaneously

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

Here an example for writing files Using Apache Camel FrameWork in a specific folder.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
        <loop>
            <constant>10000</constant>
            <to uri="file://src/data/out?fileName=${date:now:yyyymmddhhmmss}.LOOP.${header.CamelLoopIndex}.txt"/>
        </loop>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

This example does not represent really my case of use.
The goal is to create several files starting from the first file, by changing the file name each time with the constraint which these files are creates simultaneously.

**Is there a way to write all files simultaneously ?** When the Loop processing
ends, is there a way to invoke writing files in one time ?

Thxs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<threads>` to make processing files concurrently. There is an old blog entry of mine when `<threads>` was named `<async>`: http://www.davsclaus.com/2009/05/on-road-to-camel-20-concurrency-with.html

And using loop does not make sense it will just keep looping the same file.

Comment: I changed the question above, even if i add  <threads poolSize="20"> , files still not be created at once.  I can see that with the timestamp in file.